# State-of-the-art out-of-place matrix transposition in libraries such as LaPack?

Tags: matrix, transpose, lapack

I'm looking for the most efficient way to compute out-of-place transposition for large matrices (>> 1024x1024), in C/C++. I've already came across several answers in SO, however I need more "trustworthy" sources for my work (like blas/lapack).

From an online quick search I understood blas has no such function. But it was implied that Lapack implemented matrix transposition. I've been looking for awhile (including the lapack documentation) but found no answer.

I know MKL-Blas implements matrix transposition, but I'm working in a remote server and I'm not able to install it there.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenBLAS](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS) (a BLAS implementation) supports those:

- https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/OpenBLAS-Extensions

  ```
  ?omatcopy    s,d,c,z    out-of-place transpositon/copying
  ```